# Drop duplicates where some rows contain lists and others ints/strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where I want to drop rows that have duplicate IDs. For the most part, the IDs are ints and strings. Some of the ID entries, however, are lists of multiple IDs. I cannot split up these lists, but when trying to drop duplicates I get an error. For reference, I used `df = df['ID'].astype(str)` and it made no difference in the errors shown below.

Code for df:

```
d = {'ID': [999, 
123, 
F41,
99W21, 
662, 
123, 
[552, F430, R111], 
44482, 
F41, 
[M192, 5527, 7890, 111120]
]}

df = pd.Dataframe(data=d)
```

The input df ID column looks something like:

```
Index    ID
-------------
0         999
1         123
2         F41
3        99W21
4         662
5         123
6       [552, F430, R111]
7        44482
8         F41
9       [M192, 5527, 7890, 111120]
```

And I would like to drop duplicates such that the output is:

```
Index    ID
-------------
0         999
1         123
2         F41
3        99W21
4         662
5       [552, F430, R111]
6        44482
7       [M192, 5527, 7890, 111120]
```

I have tried `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID'], inplace=True)` which gives me the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-0186aa1e1043> in <module>
      3 # Reset index and drop CID duplicates
----> 4 df.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID'], inplace=True)
      5 df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in drop_duplicates(self, subset, keep, inplace)
   4907 
   4908         inplace = validate_bool_kwarg(inplace, "inplace")
-> 4909         duplicated = self.duplicated(subset, keep=keep)
   4910 
   4911         if inplace:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in duplicated(self, subset, keep)
   4967 
   4968         vals = (col.values for name, col in self.items() if name in subset)
-> 4969         labels, shape = map(list, zip(*map(f, vals)))
   4970 
   4971         ids = get_group_index(labels, shape, sort=False, xnull=False)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in f(vals)
   4945         def f(vals):
   4946             labels, shape = algorithms.factorize(
-> 4947                 vals, size_hint=min(len(self), _SIZE_HINT_LIMIT)
   4948             )
   4949             return labels.astype("i8", copy=False), len(shape)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    206                 else:
    207                     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 208             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    209 
    210         return wrapper

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/algorithms.py in factorize(values, sort, order, na_sentinel, size_hint)
    670 
    671         labels, uniques = _factorize_array(
--> 672             values, na_sentinel=na_sentinel, size_hint=size_hint, na_value=na_value
    673         )
    674 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/algorithms.py in _factorize_array(values, na_sentinel, size_hint, na_value)
    506     table = hash_klass(size_hint or len(values))
    507     uniques, labels = table.factorize(
--> 508         values, na_sentinel=na_sentinel, na_value=na_value
    509     )
    510 

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.factorize()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable._unique()

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

And also `df = pd.DataFrame(np.unique(df), columns=df.columns)`, which gives the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-5b335a526fd5> in <module>
      3 # Reset index and drop CID duplicates
----> 4 df = pd.DataFrame(np.unique(df), columns=df.columns)
      5 df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

<__array_function__ internals> in unique(*args, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py in unique(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts, axis)
    260     ar = np.asanyarray(ar)
    261     if axis is None:
--> 262         ret = _unique1d(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts)
    263         return _unpack_tuple(ret)
    264 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py in _unique1d(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts)
    308         aux = ar[perm]
    309     else:
--> 310         ar.sort()
    311         aux = ar
    312     mask = np.empty(aux.shape, dtype=np.bool_)

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'
```

If there is a way around this, I am not sure what it is, so any help would be useful.

Comment: Please provide code for reproducing your dataframe.

Comment: What kind of error you get with `df['ID'].astype(str).drop_duplicates()`?

Comment: @FelipeLanza when I do that, it doesn't drop duplicates, it leaves `NaN` in its place. I can't just `dropna`, either, as some are naturally `NaN`.

Comment: I cannot replicate the error, `df = df.astype(str).drop_duplicates()` using your data works fine for me.

Comment: @FelipeLanza I do not see the error either. Example code: https://repl.it/repls/WordyIdolizedProgrammingmacro

Answer (score 0):

unhashable type: 'list' error means Pandas trying to use list as an hash argument.

[All of Python's immutable built-in objects are hashable, while no mutable containers (such as lists or dictionaries) are.](https://docs.python.org/3.1/glossary.html)

Try to convert column to string and drop the duplicates. and change it back to dataframe

```
df = df['ID'].astype(str).drop_duplicates().to_frame()
```